# Firebase: property does not exist on type error

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I'm getting a new error on my Firebase `8.9.1` auth service and am not sure how it should be changed. Is this an overhaul of FB auth or a code change?

> (alias) enum SignupMethods import SignupMethods Property
> 'EMAIL_PASSWORD' does not exist on type '{ GOOGLE: () =>
> GoogleAuthProvider; FACEBOOK: () => FacebookAuthProvider; GITHUB: ()
> => GithubAuthProvider; }'.ts(2339)

```
async socialLogin(method: SignupMethods, roles?: UserRoles[]) {
    if (!roles?.length) roles = [];

  const provider = {
    [SignupMethods.GOOGLE]: () => new 
 firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
    [SignupMethods.FACEBOOK]: () => new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider(),
    [SignupMethods.GITHUB]: () => new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider()
  }[method];
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(method)` before that? It's mostly like `EMAIL_PASSWORD` and is undefined?

Comment: Hmm yes. It's `SignupMethods` is an enum.